# At what layer of the OSI model does ipfw works?

Tags: tcp, packet-loss, ipfw, dummynet

Clearly, when I use iptables to drop packets in output of a sender A, the TCP instance of A re-send them because it never gets ACK from the receiver B of those lost packets. 
In the end, depending on the probability of drop (>0), all data from A might get to the receiver B.
Packet loss thus induces network delays and the increase of TCP segments being send on the network.
Will I face the same situation using ipfw ?
Are the packets handled before or after the TCP state machine ?
All information I could get, even of the dummynet official page, is not clear about it, even the googletechtalk.

I thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: At no layer. The OSI model doesn't apply to anything except OSI. TCP/IP has its own, earlier, viable, working model, which is what you should be asking about. It mystifies me why the OSI model is still being taught, and asked about, twenty years and more after it crashed and burned. Your actual question doesn't appear to have anything to do with any layer model whatsoever.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help